# Is there a more verbose version of the command `httpd -S`?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf

The command `httpd -S` displays your `VirtualHost`'s and Configuration Files, and the IPs and Ports they are listening on. Is there a similar command that also shows you the directives applied to teach Vhost?

Maybe something that parses all the configuration files and shows the resulting configuration in a more standard format.

Comment: I don't think Apache has anything like this. Of course nginx can do this, but that doesn't help you.

Comment: Would there even be such "standard format", considering all the possible configurations? This is probably not offered simply because it would just print out the configuration files.